# Draggable text on canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a whiteboard app where I want to drag text around the whiteboard with my mouse. Below is my dragText() so far where I handle mouse events etc. I tested click and move mouse events, and they both work, however the function still doesn't work as intended (I can't drag the text). I am out of ideas.

Also I noticed that in the function handleMouseDown, whenever I click somewhere on canvas where text coordinates are out of bounds, everything works fine there, but whenever I click on the text (and so the if statement in the for loop becomes true) suddenly whole canvas returns true (function textInBounds). Why is that?

```js
function dragText() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('board'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    font = '14px sans-serif';
  var sketch = document.querySelector('#sketch');
  var sketch_style = getComputedStyle(sketch);
  canvas.width = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('width'));
  canvas.height = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('height'));

  var texts = [];
  texts.push({ text: "Hello", x: 20, y: 20 });
  var StartX;
  var StartY;

  for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
    var text = texts[i];
    ctx.position = 'absolute';
    ctx.font = font;
    ctx.fillText(text.text, text.x, text.y);
  }
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    handleMouseDown(e);
  })

  function handleMouseDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    StartX = parseInt(e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left);
    StartY = parseInt(e.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top);

    for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
      if (textInBounds(StartX, StartY, i)) {
        selectElement(i);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
          handleMouseMove(e);
        })
      } else {
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  var selectedElement;

  function selectElement(element) {
    selectedElement = element;
  }

  function textInBounds(x, y, i) {
    var text = texts[i];
    return (x <= (text.x + ctx.measureText(text.text).width) && x > text.x);
  }

  function handleMouseMove(e) {
    if (selectedElement < 0) {
      return;
    }

    e.preventDefault();

    var MouseX, MouseY

    MouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left);
    MouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top);

    var dx = MouseX - StartX;
    var dy = MouseX - StartY;
    StartX = MouseX;
    StartY = MouseX;

    var text = texts[selectedElement];
    text.x += dx;
    text.y += dy;
  }

  {
    function handleMouseUp(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      selectedElement = -1;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML

```
render()
    {
        return(
            <div class="sketch" id="sketch">
                <canvas className="board" id="board">  </canvas>
            </div>
            )
    }
```

CSS

```
.board
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.sketch
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you add CSS and HTML?

Comment: @Justin yes, added